# Evaluate mit-scheme code in a buffer in emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs24, mit-scheme

`M-x eval-buffer` evaluates lisp code in a buffer. How do I evaluate mit-scheme code written in a buffer?

Comment: See official documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/GNU-Emacs-Interface.html) and [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExScheme).

Comment: Have a look at (http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/).
It's got support for Racket and Guile already. It should be relatively easy to add
support for mit-scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vanilla emacs you can do `run-scheme`, to start a `scheme` repl. Then you can use the different functions available for evaluating the scheme code in the repl.

For example given you are in `scheme-mode`, suppose you have following code in the scheme buffer

```
(define (test a b)
  (+ a b))
```

After starting the repl with `run-scheme`, you can go to the end of function definition and do `C-x C-e`, to evaluate it in the repl. Now you have the `test` function defined in the repl, to test this type the following in the buffer

```
(test 1 3)
```

Go to the end of the sexp and do `C-x C-e` again, this will print 4 in the repl. Also you can use `C-c C-l` to load the entire file at once.

Do `C-h m` to find out the different keybindings for evaluating scheme code. You can also use the menu to discover the different functions available.

Other option is to use `slime` as far as I know you will need some extra setup to use `mit-scheme` with slime, the instructions are present in the `contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm` file in slime's main folder.